# Call PHP variable to html input

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to call PHP variable into HTML input field. Please see below code.

```
<html>
<?php
    $A_variable = $_GET['some text'];

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "document.getElementById('A_input').value = ";$A_variable;
echo "</script>";
?>
<input type="text" id="A_input" name="A_input" placeholder="input" Readonly>
</html>
```

Please, advice am I trying in a proper way? Your assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: You have there syntax error in JS (missing quotes around, if `$A_variable` isn't a number), syntax error in PHP (`;` instead of `.`) and you call the script before `input` exists. Check the console.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element covers *one* of the several things that are wrong with tthis code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Javascript to achieve that,

simply,

```
<html>
<?php
    $A_variable = $_GET['some text'];
?>
<input type="text" id="A_input" name="A_input" value="<?php echo $A_variable; ?>" placeholder="input" Readonly>
</html>
```

[Edited]
Looking at code above we can make it even simpler

```
<html>
<input type="text" id="A_input" name="A_input" value="<?php echo $_GET['some text']; ?>" placeholder="input" Readonly>
</html>
```

PS: This way is not advisable since it vulnerable to XSS attack.

Simplest way to prevent XSS attack is by using [stip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
<html>
<input type="text" id="A_input" name="A_input" value="<?php echo strip_tags($_GET['some text']); ?>" placeholder="input" Readonly>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. XSS. 2. Why `$A_variable`, when you can echo `$_GET['some text']` directly inside `value` attribute??

Comment: 1. XSS - Obviously yes, but it is whole different topic.
2. Agree. Just to make question owner can see how a variable can easily be outputted to html tags.

Comment: _"XSS - Obviously yes, but it is whole different topic"_ - It should be included in the answer. People tend to just copy/paste answers here, thinking they are totally fine. If we see security issues, we should point them out and, at least, give them a reference to where they can read more about them.

Comment: You're quite new here. When the code is vulnerable (XSS in this case), the answer should solve that, if it's just in adding one PHP function more around echoes variable.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Yes I am quite new here. I will update the answer accordingly

Comment: @panther I have updated the answer based on your comment. Please let me know if it is good enough or can be corrected.

Comment: `strip_tags` will not protect this code from XSS attacks. `some+text="%20onmouseover="alert('xss')"`

Comment: @anasceym: strip_tags doesn't solve XSS and modify value (why '2 > 1'  (two is greater than 1) should be invalid input?). The right way is to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: **Always** use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to properly encode as HTML the data you use to generate HTML. Without it, the generated HTML is invalid in many situations.